# How can I use breadcrumbs with symfony2.1?

Tags: php, symfony-2.1

I need to use breadcrumbs on my site.

Can anyone guide me any bundle which can help me?

Or If someone can guide me how can I program it. I have no idea how to start with
I have many levels of classes.

LIke

`School--Principal--Teacher--student.`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Symfony 2.1, you will need to use the 2.1 branch:

`"whiteoctober/breadcrumbs-bundle": "2.1.x-dev"`

Comment: Good addition to @Carlos Granados' answer.